# How to monitor and automatically restart mysql?

Tags: mysql, debian

I'm running mysql on Debian.

Is there a way to monitor mysql and restart it automatically if it locks up? For example sometimes the server starts to take 100% of cpu and starts running very slowly. If I restart mysql, things clear up and the server starts working fine, but I'm not always present to restart it manually.

Is there a way to monitor mysql and if the cpu is above 95% for more than 10 minutes straight then then mysql will automatically be restarted

Comment: It would probably be better to find out *why* mySQL does that, it shouldn't do that on a regular basis. Voting to migrate to Serverfault.com

Comment: I wish I knew, the same query that takes a second to execute after I restart the server, was taking 300 seconds before the restart. I'm not sure not to trace down the problem.

Comment: MONyog has a "Sniffer" feature which uses "Show Full Processlist;" query to capture query details, you can set a threshold for `query execution` and if a query reaches that threshold then it gets killed automatically and you will receive an email which states query details.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a cronjob to use

```
show processlist;
```

`show processlist` will return column `Time` and `Id`,
you can add more logic to check,
like query stuck for more than 600 seconds and the query is `SELECT`,
you can use `Id` value to perform `kill $id;`

This is safer than blindly restarting your server.

And if you have segregate between read/write (meaning read only SQL will use user with read privileges only), this can even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Use this bash script to check every minute.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Checking whether MySQL is alive or not
if mysqladmin ping | grep "alive"; then
   echo "MySQL is up"
else
   sudo service mysql restart
fi
```

`